# Adjective if adjective usage with commas

Tags: commas

What's the correct way to construct the following structure?

```
adjective + if + adjective
```

Her careful, if paranoid, approach meant that she didn't make any mistakes.

Have I put the commas in the correct place?

Comment: Yes; this is a contrastive parenthesis.